# A way to load in PHP require_once Data from the current file

Tags: php, html

Is it Possible to add Data inside a require_once. I Cant explain it that well so i just show it.

So when i load the index page, its going to load an structure with data inside.

```
// Index
<?php
require_once('/structure.php');
// THIS DATA NEEDS TO SEND TO STRUCTURE, INCLUDING PHP
if (2 > 1)
{
  ?>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <?php
}
?>
```

This is the Structure

```
// '/structure.php'
<table>
 <?php 
 // HERE THE DATA NEED TO LOAD
 ?>
</table>
```

So it would look eventually like this at the index.

```
// Index
<table>
 if (2 > 1)
 {
   ?>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <?php
 }
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: DId you try it, thats always the first test

Comment: You may find that this would eventually disappear up its own exhaust pipe

Comment: I did try it. Only i just cant find a good way to execute (Thats why i am here xd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bad way to structure your code. That being said, here's the least-bad way I can think of.

**index.php**

```
<?php

$requireVersion = '2';

require_once('/structure.php');
```

**structure.php**

```
<table>
    <?php
      $requireFile = '/structure_include' . $requireVersion . '.php';
      if ( file_exists($requireFile) ) {
        require_once($requireFile);
      }
    ?>
</table>
```

**structure_include1.php**

```
<?php

if (1 > 2)
{
  echo '<td>Jack</td>';
}
```

**structure_include2.php**

```
<?php

if (2 > 1)
{
  echo '<td>Jill</td>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking it is possible to require a required file. But it would be an endless loop. 
May I suggest:

**index.php**

```
<table>
<?php 
require_once('structure.php');
if(2 > 1){
 if(isset($_SESSION['temp_markup']){
 echo $_SESSION['temp_markup'];
}
}
?>
</table>
```

**structure.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$html = '<td>Jill</td>';
//add session or some storage manner
$_SESSION['temp_markup'] = $html;
?>
```

That would be my idea based on this rather confusing question.

Comment: I had to edit  the answer. What you had and at first flance, looked like it was all in one file, which looked like it would be outputting before header.

Comment: However, how is the first file to sustain sessions? *That*, could be prone to outputting before header. If the session is started inside `structure.php` which appears to be, it will fail.